# PHP Foreach variables to dynamic javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a PHP foreach loop that is presenting thumbnails based on how many there is in the database. I already have a popup that is being triggered through jQuery and the popup HTML is right now static no matter which picture I click on.
How can I make so that when I click on one of the thumbnails, the popup shows with the data for that picture?
I have basically zero knowledge of javascript/jquery and I am really stuck now so if anyone would like to help me out how to do this I would be really grateful!

```
<?php foreach($comPhotos as $comPhoto) : 
            $photoSrc = $comPhoto->img_src;
            $photoThumbnail = $comPhoto->img_preview;
            $photoID = $comPhoto->ID;
            // other photo data that I want to pass on to the modal
            ?>
            <!-- PHOTO PREVIEW -->
            <div class="photo-preview small popup-picture-trigger">
                    <!-- PHOTO PREVIEW IMAGE -->
                    <figure class="photo-preview-image liquid">
                        <img src="<?php echo $photoThumbnail;?>" alt="photo-preview-01">
                    </figure>
                    <!-- /PHOTO PREVIEW IMAGE -->
                <!-- PHOTO PREVIEW INFO -->
                <div class="photo-preview-info">
                    <!-- REACTION COUNT LIST -->
                    <div class="reaction-count-list">
                        <!-- REACTION COUNT -->
                        <div class="reaction-count negative">
                            <!-- REACTION COUNT ICON -->
                            <svg class="reaction-count-icon icon-thumbs-up">
                                <use xlink:href="#svg-thumbs-up"></use>
                            </svg>
                            <!-- /REACTION COUNT ICON -->

                            <!-- REACTION COUNT TEXT -->
                            <p class="reaction-count-text">12</p>
                            <!-- /REACTION COUNT TEXT -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /REACTION COUNT -->

                        <!-- REACTION COUNT -->
                        <div class="reaction-count negative">
                            <!-- REACTION COUNT ICON -->
                            <svg class="reaction-count-icon icon-comment">
                                <use xlink:href="#svg-comment"></use>
                            </svg>
                            <!-- /REACTION COUNT ICON -->

                            <!-- REACTION COUNT TEXT -->
                            <p class="reaction-count-text">5</p>
                            <!-- /REACTION COUNT TEXT -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /REACTION COUNT -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /REACTION COUNT LIST -->
                </div>
                <!-- /PHOTO PREVIEW INFO -->
            </div>
            <!-- /PHOTO PREVIEW -->
        <?php endforeach;?>
```

This is the code to define and trigger the popup in external .js file

```
app.plugins.createPopup({
  container: '.popup-picture',
  trigger: '.popup-picture-trigger',
  sticky: true,
  overlay: {
    color: '21, 21, 31',
    opacity: .93
  },
  animation: {
    type: 'translate-in-fade',
    speed: .3,
    translateOffset: 40
  }
});
```

Here is the popup div that I want to act like a modal with the dynamic content from each foreach. (Being used ouside of the foreach to prevent a lot of repeted code)

```
<div class="popup-picture" id="popup-picture">
<--CONTENT-->
    <div class="popup-picture-image-wrap">
        <!-- POPUP PICTURE IMAGE -->
        <figure class="popup-picture-image" style="width:auto;max-height:749px;">
            <img src="<?php echo $photoSrc;?>" id="popup-puppy" name="popup-puppy" class="popup-puppy" alt="cover-04">
        </figure>
        <!-- /POPUP PICTURE IMAGE -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Don't just provide requirements and expect code as a result.  If your javascript/jquery knowlege is lacking, work on that. Find some tutorials. For what you have here, you need to look into event handling for the click, how to read info from DOM elements then how to update DOM elements.

Comment: I'm very well aware of that Stack Overflow is not a code writing service and I don't expect anyone to give me a full source code and neither did I ask for it. I provided the code I have with a try of an explanation of what I want to achieve. Asking for help is not asking to have the work done but at least pointing in the direction of where I need to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so just set the image you want to show as a data attribute with php then grab it via jquery

```
 <div class="photo-preview small popup-picture-trigger" data-full-image="$photoSrc">
```

then in your js (jquery)

```
$(".popup-picture-trigger").on("click",function(){
    
    var fullImg = $(this).data("full-image"); 

    $("#popup-puppy").attr("src",fullImg); 
    
    
});
```

You click on the popup-picture-trigger div which contains the path to the full image as a data attribute data-full-image="$photoSrc" you attach a click handler to .popup-picture-trigger and replace the modal image src with the image path stored in data-full-image

Comment: edited above to include your own variable names the answer was correct you just needed to replace the full image source with your own variable name